# How can I get the list of common references from different scientific articles?

Tags: citations, bibliometrics

I have a question regarding a literature review for my research. I would like to know if there is a way to **get the list of common references to different articles automatically**.

Example: I have these 2 articles (in Mendeley Reference Manager, as PDF and DOI URL)

- Roy, S., Prasanna Venkatesan, S., & Goh, M. (2021). Healthcare services: A systematic review of patient-centric logistics issues using simulation. Journal of the Operational Research Society, 72(10), 2342-2364. https://doi.org/10.1080/01605682.2020.1790306
- Brailsford, S. C., Eldabi, T., Kunc, M., Mustafee, N., & Osorio, A. F. (2019). Hybrid simulation modelling in operational research: A state-of-the-art review. European Journal of Operational Research, 278(3), 721-737. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2018.10.025

And, from the manual/visual check of the references for each article (in the pdf and the web URL), I know that the reference :

Brailsford, S. C., Harper, P. R., Patel, B., & Pidd, M. (2009). An analysis of the academic literature on simulation and modeling in health care. Journal of Simulation, 3(3), 130-140. https://doi.org/10.1057/jos.2009.10 .

is part of the list of common references for the previous 2 articles.

I don't know how to tackle this problem. I know how to use python and I am using Mendeley Reference Manager to manage my research references.

Thank you all

--EDIT---

I have found some different approaches to find a solution.

- [Citation Gecko](https://citationgecko.azurewebsites.net/) (https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/148736/161318)

Solve exactly what I asked for in this question. Free, simple and really easy to use. Recommended when one is starting a literature review with some articles that are related to the research because you can find some precedent and future work-related.

- [ResearchRabbit](https://www.researchrabbit.ai/) (https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/177955/161318)

I have tested this application and it is very great: free, show earlier/later relevant research papers, suggested authors, visualize the connections... I recommended 100% for a nice and user-friendly literature review.

The reader can find more in the following related topics/questions :

- [Map (tree) of citations/references](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13329/map-tree-of-citations-references/122838#122838)
- [List of citation graph browsers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/82638/list-of-citation-graph-browsers)
- [Is there a tool to visualize the academic citation network around a researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/86509/is-there-a-tool-to-visualize-the-academic-citation-network-around-a-researcher?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C30.3953)

Comment: Here is a solution in R (but you can adjust it to Python): https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/92890/how-to-identify-the-publications-that-cite-two-specific-papers/169714#169714

Comment: Thank you @anpami. The post that you mentioned is answer the inverse process: they found a list of DOIs that have cited both work1 and work2. I am looking for a list of DOIs cited in both, work1 and work2.